# why is including this header causing this error?

Tags: c++

This is a header and source for a class I have. There are similar other classes, all of which have to be included in one central class.

However, including the file `GameObject.h` in the header below causes an error:

```
error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Node'
```

Although this error seems a little obscure, I have a slightly older working version of the code, and the only difference is that Node now inherits from GameObject.

Header:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include "GameObject.h"

class Mesh;

class Node : public GameObject
{
public: 
Node(Mesh& mesh);
};

#endif
```

source:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Mesh.h"

Node::Node(Mesh& mesh) : GameObject(mesh)
{

}
```

In the call stack I am eventually pointed to a declaration of a vector of node objects as the cause, but I have no idea why this is happening as there are other objects that also inherit from gameObject that are also in vectors.

```
std::vector<Node> nodes;
```

Comment: Why does `GameObject.h` need to to include `Node.h`?  Please show the code.

Comment: why are you including "node.h" in "gameobject.h"?

Comment: where did I say I was doing that? I re read the question and can't see it. Bad grammar on my part?

Comment: @SirYakalot: To have circular inclusion you need to include "node.h" from "gameobject.h".

Comment: It's a *very* good idea for clean dependency control to put declarations in `myclass.hpp` and the implementation in `myclass.cpp` and make *the first line* of the source file `#include "myclass.hpp". Then add all the headers that you need for the implementation.

Comment: Perhaps circular inclusion is the wrong phrase. Basically a class is including a number of things like Node, all which have GameObject.h in their headers. Is this not that kind of problem? Where you can't have more than one being included?

Comment: What's wrong with this as-is? I see no inclusion circle unless `GameObject.h` includes `Node.h` as suggested by others.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was under the impression that you should include as little as possible in headers so that their not included in other classes you need those headers in.

Comment: @SirYakalot It's not a problem to include a header from multiple places.

Comment: @jli well if I stop this class from inheriting from GameObject, it fixes the problem, so it must be something to do with multiple includes, right?

Comment: What problem is there? You said it works without the forward declaration.

Comment: I'll change the question, clearly I am misunderstanding.

Comment: While you are at it, please provide a minimal, complete sample program. (See http://sscce.org/.) A complete program is one that we can paste into an editor and compile to see exactly the same error you see. A minimal program is one that contains no lines unrelated to your problem. In this specific case, you should be able to produce a complete program in three-files with approximately 10 lines in each file.

Comment: @Rob sorry no, I just tried but I can't seem to replicate the problem in a cut down program. I just don't know enough to be able to do that, for all I know this error could be coming from anywhere. I only know that if Node doesn't inherit from GameObject, I don't get the error.

Comment: So cut down smaller chunks. Start with `main()`. If its body is empty, does the problem go away? Move on to the other types, unrelated to GameObject, Node, and Mesh. If you delete (for example) `Player`, does the problem go away? What about `Board`? Keep removing things a little bit at a time until you have the smallest program that still produces an error.

Comment: By the way, producing a minimal complete program is one of the "wax-on, wax-off" requests (ref: Karate Kid). The act of removing bits and pieces from your program reinforces your own debugging skills, and also makes it more likely that you will solve the problem entirely on your own. It only *appears* that I require it for selfish reasons.

Comment: @SirYakalot: That is true also, and it's not a contradiction. The header should only contain the minimal amount of headers necessary for the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

> However, including the file GameObject.h in the header below causes an error:

This implies that the only difference between the working and non-working code is the inclusion of that header file, **but**,

> I have a slightly older working version of the code, and the only difference is that Node now inherits from GameObject.

This implies that there is another difference: `Node` now inherits from `GameObject`. Which is the the inclusion of the inheritance that is causing the problem?

Assuming that it is the inheritance that is causing the problem, I guess you have a private or otherwise unavailable `operator=` in `GameObject`. Since `vector`s like to copy objects around, you'll be needing an `operator=` available in both `GameObject` and `Node`.

In the alternative, you may have a reference inside `GameObject` that is preventing the compiler from providing its automatic assignment operator, thus preventing `Node` from having an automatic assignment operator.

In sum: If, inside `GameObject`, you have either a private `operator=` or a non-static reference (like `Mesh&`), then you will need to create an `Node::operator=` for `vector` to use.

*References*:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983787(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I DO have a reference to a mesh inside gameObject. You sir, are amazing. why would this not be affecting the other classes that inherit from gameobject?

Comment: I can only assume that there is no call for `operator=` in any of the other objects. You don't every say `player1 = player1` or `players.push_back(opponent)`, or in any other way require the assignment operator.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774508/c-c2582-compiler-wont-auto-generate-default-ctor-or-operator